# how to style first image of all posts in blogger blog?

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger

I want to justify the first image of all posts in my blogger blog please help. Actually, the first images of my all posts are aligned to either left or right and on smaller screens such as a mobile view or tablet view, the words along with the first images are shown as half because of the smaller area alongside the image. if I will justify only the first image of all posts then their half-words will not be shown and instead, it will be shown in a separate paragraph. I know how to justify all images of posts but I want to style only the first image of all my posts in blogger.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - After that please edit your question to meet those guidelines.

Comment: to select the first image you can use: `img:first-of-type` or `img:nth-of-type(1)`

Answer (score -1):

You can add css to article -> first img tag.

```css
article img:first-child{
    display: inline;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="post-wrapper">
<article>
<img alt="Bitcoin Mining not possible with gold and silver" border="0" height="398" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-85lwx5Ucm5o/W1Zb_wuJn6I/AAAAAAAATEw/hbJnnVzARMc6rx_cdQ3NanaN_PY_2Z1HwCHMYCw/image124_thumb11?imgmax=800" style="background-image: none; border: 0px currentcolor; display: inline; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;" title="" width="592">
</article>
</div>
</html>
```